# Installing Tridion 2011 SP1 : Content delivery server

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We are installing SDL Tridion 2011 sp1.  After reading installation manual we came accross some queries.

How the incoming folder is created on CDS ? Do we need to create it manually or it will be created by startCDinstaller.bat?

In our case we will be publishing content using http/https so we will follow step 6.4.5 of installation manual.  In this step nothing is mentioned about creation of incoming folder.

Is it must to run startCDinstaller.bat so that required assemblies will be registered, and config and Jar files are copied to CDS server ?

Our CDS server architecture is:

1. Our portal (display site) is configured in the IIS which is pointing to `d:\Inetpub\Myportal`
2. HTTPUpload website is configured in the IIS which is pointing to `d:\Inetpub\MyHTTPUpload`

Answer (score 7):

**How the incoming folder is created on CDS ? Do we need to create it manually or it will be created by startCDinstaller.bat?**

**A :** It depends. If your IIS site App Pool user has permissions to create it will create automatically. But, I would recommend you create this manually and provide permissions to the AppPool User.

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_663JDNNNDHDH889595JDJDJD

Configure the IIS user who will be executing the HTTPUpload.aspx Web page to have modify access to the Content Deployer location for incoming content. By default, the IIS user is the identity running the SDL Tridion Application Pool (which typically is the Network Service user).

**Is it must to run startCDinstaller.bat so that required assemblies will be registered, and config and Jar files are copied to CDS server ?**

**A :** It is not must to run the startCDinstaller.bat. If you are running as .net Web Application, the dll/jars/config will be simply to be copied under /bin directory.

My personal preference is always configure manually (and most follow the same procedure - universal procedure). Check below documentation for steps to be followed.

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_708AA488429D4457AC303DD121B22183

Answer (score 2):

Please follow Nuno's excellent installer guide [here](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/07/manually-configuring-tridion-2011-net.html)

The HTTPUpload website is your 'Deployer' and the URL of that site you put into the Publish Target.  Try hitting it in the browser first.

I did not use the .bat file - Nuno's instructions are all that is needed.